# Calculating Time Complexity (consecutive loops)

Tags: time, time-complexity

For the following code:

```
int func(int x, int y)
{
   int flag=0;

   for(flag=0; flag<x; flag++)
   {
      ....
   }

   for(flag=0; flag<y; flag++)
   {
      ....
   }

   return 0;
}
```

for the following cases the time complexity (my understanding) is -

```
x > y  => O(x+y)
y < x  => O(x+y)
x = y  => O(2x)
```

Can someone verify if I am right?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just so you know, the questions and answers here can be formatted to look nicer and be easier to read. You should read about the formatting rules here so that you can format your code snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: In fact, since you didn't use the code format, everything after the "<" sign is lost. So we can't actually see your code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x > y  => O(x+y) -- yes. But if, x = O(y), then just O(x).

y < x  => O(x+y) -- yes. Same explanation above.

x = y  => O(2x) -- not quite. You ignore the constant factor in Big O analysis. The idea is that when x goes to infinity, the '2' or the constant would contribute that much towards the rate of increase of the function.

x = y^2 => O(y^2) -- Another characteristic of Big O analysis is that you only consider the major term.

An excellent introduction to Big O analysis can be found here an [video](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/) lecture format. Check out the second lecture for Big O analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation doesn't use constant multipliers. Ie, there is no *O(2n)*, only *O(n)*. This is in contrast to exponentials, where it is common to see *O(2^n)*, etc.

Your function is linear, so if `x == y`, then the order of magnitude is simply listed as *O(x)*.